# IDE that runs completely in the browser completely client side (html/js/css only)

Tags: javascript, html, web-browser, ide, css

There are numerous IDEs accessible through the browser ranging from things like JSFiddle to VSCode and beyond.

I'm looking for something like an html/css/js app that acts like an IDE. Clearly, it won't be able to run any languages other than javascript or something ported to WebAssembly.

### Edit

Based on @depperm's comment, I'm adding this:
I think what I'm describing is a client-side app. I made [this trivial example](https://gist.github.com/abalter/23f3e66f5e6a0ef7b0e5d9c13adae220) based on [this codepen](https://codepen.io/Souleste/pen/xxwvVva).

You might be able to view it [here](https://gistpreview.github.io/?23f3e66f5e6a0ef7b0e5d9c13adae220) or [here](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://gist.githubusercontent.com/abalter/23f3e66f5e6a0ef7b0e5d9c13adae220/raw/4a2f7b194a7c53d51b1087319b77aaac03325f39/simple-codepen-example.html)

Comment: why are the IDEs you list un-acceptable? Are you trying to embed it in a webpage? Does it have to run code or just highlight?

Comment: @depperm I made an update to answer your question. Not "embed in a webpage" but _be_ the webpage or app.

Comment: There is a list on Wikipedia: [Online integrated development environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_integrated_development_environment). I would add that GitHub and Gitlab have  lots of features for in-browser editing.

Comment: Try [jslinux](https://bellard.org/jslinux/) In 2011 Fabrice Bellard wrote a Javascript PC Emulator running Linux (and other OSs) inside your browser. You will get a shell with the 4.12 kernel, and With some tweaking  you can run and install any program then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JupyterLite](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) offers JupyterLab IDE (but also a Jupyter Notebook v7 alpha) running entirely in the browser and by default enables execution of JavaScript and Python (ipyodide kernel, though the time to first execution can take up to a minute as it downloads Pyodide and which is WebAssembly port of CPython). Additional kernels are available for installation:

- [sqlite](https://github.com/jupyterlite/xeus-sqlite-kernel)
- [lua](https://github.com/jupyterlite/xeus-lua-kernel)
- [wren](https://github.com/jupyterlite/xeus-wren-kernel)
- [xeus-python](https://github.com/jupyterlite/xeus-python-kernel) - another Python kernel

and more are in active development:

- [ruby](https://github.com/kateinoigakukun/jupyterlite-ruby-kernel)

Comment: Yes! I just ran across that yesterday and was going to report back. This is an example of what I was asking for. Unfortunately, I hate Jupyter as a development environment. It's great for presentation. But it does meet the requirements of the question and establishes proof of principle.

Answer (score -1):

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) is very IDE oriented and runs it's system directly within your browser and not on their servers.  It has a ton of functionality from basic JS or TS program all the way to heavy frameworks like React, Angular, and Node.

It's free and a great resource.

Comment: It's actually just their version of VS Code for web. If you open the developer panel, you can see that when you do things like create a file or save a file the app is making GET requests to the server.

The simple test is to do **File>Save As>web page complete** in the browser. If you can run the thing you downloaded, then it's purely client-side.

Answer (score -1):

Easily test or find Code that you can use in your project using BALKAN Code

[Hello BALKAN Code](https://code.balkan.app/Hello-BALKAN-Code#JS)

[image]

Comment: Requires a server.

Comment: @abalter, what do you mean? It is similar to JSFiddle

Comment: So does JS Fiddle. It's not an app I could, for instance run on my own machine let alone without a server.

Check out the gist I made as well as https://golden-layout.com/. Together these could be made into something like an IDE. I was hoping someone had already built one.

Comment: I see, you are promoting your IDE, it looks promising BTW

Comment: Absolutely not! It's something I _wish_ existed. I want to make a minimally functional app similar to RStudio that runs in a web page and can run javascript or python via pyodide which could work this way: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/build-python-code-editor-using-codemirror-and-pyodide/